# Migrations are not applying to specific model

Tags: python, django

The problem is whenever I try to migrate changes, migrations does'nt applying to this specific app which is named as Userinfo. The messege in my terminal is

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, books_details, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

And that app is not listed in my above list also i don't know what could be the reason

Models.py of that app

```
from django.db import models
import os
# from django.conf import settings
def upload_rename(instance,filename):
    exe=filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename=instance.user_name+'.'+exe
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join('images','profile_image',instance.user_name,filename))
    except:
        pass
    return os.path.join('profile_image',instance.user_name,filename)

class Userinfo(models.Model):
    ''' User info '''
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False,primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_rename, blank=True)
    ''' The Change I added '''
    varified_user =models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Admin.py of that app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Userinfo
admin.site.register(Userinfo)
```

INSTALLED_APP in setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'userinfo',
    'rest_framework',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'books_details',
]
```

Migrations

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import userinfo.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Userinfo',
            fields=[
                ('user_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('full_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('user_email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('college_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('city', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('country', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('profile_img', models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=userinfo.models.upload_rename)),
                ('varified_user', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Here are some images i think you should see
[image: Terminal Message when i try to migrate]

I don't know why it says create model userinfo as it was pre-existing
Database screenshot
[image: Screenshot of my database where i want to apply changes]
please any can help with this???

Comment: Did you add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the project's `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes i have included in installed_apps

Comment: Can you try `userinfo.apps.UserinfoConfig` instead of only `userinfo`?

Comment: can you please show us the migration file under `userinfo/migrations` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you need first to run `makemigrations` command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations userinfo
```

and then run `migrate` command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

refer to this tuto from django docx :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models for more explanations

> By running **makemigrations**, you’re telling Django that you’ve made some changes to your models (in this case, you’ve made new ones) and that you’d like the changes to be stored as a migration.

## Update

in some cases, it's better to restart the migration process from scratch just to unlock such situation
so, since you're in **development mode** i would suggest you deleting:

- the database (or better make a backup)
- migrations files under `migrations` folder for each app
- and don't forget `__pycache__` folders

and then rerun `makemigrations` and  `migrate` commands respectively

Comment: So when I tried this ```python manage.py makemigrations userinfo``` migration file got generated but when migrate ```python manage.py migrate userinfo``` it shows no migrations to apply and there is no change in my database also I have added my migrations file which was generated in my code above

Comment: I have added some images please see them also